# C#: some of machines are throwing following error: Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass'

Tags: c#, datagridview

I had created a C# function which saves `DataGridView` to Excel which works well on most of machines.
However, some of machines are throwing following error:

`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID ‘{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}’ failed due to the following error: Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)).`

Is there any way I can fix this issue?

This is my source code:

```
private bool dataGridView_ExportToExcel(string fileName, DataGridView dgv, string ext, bool chart)
{
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
    Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();

    if (excelApp == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No Excel has been installed!");
        return false;
    }

    Excel.Workbook wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(true);
    Excel._Worksheet workSheet = wb.Worksheets.get_Item(1) as Excel._Worksheet;
    workSheet.Name = "C#";

    // Print Contents
    for (int r = 0; r < dgv.Rows.Count; r++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            workSheet.Cells[r + 2, i + 1] = dgv.Rows[r].Cells[i].Value;
        }
    }

    workSheet.Columns.AutoFit();
    wb.SaveAs(fileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

    wb.Close(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    excelApp.Quit();
    releaseObject(excelApp);
    releaseObject(workSheet);
    releaseObject(wb);

    return true;
}
```

I am using `.NET framework 4.6.1` environment.

Thank you for reading. have a nice day :)

Comment: Which version of Excel do they have, and which version on the other PCs? Are you using the Primary Interop Assemblies?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I see troubled PCs are using office 2013 in windows 10.

Comment: And the others?

Comment: @Charlieface I was able to resolve this issue by erasing 1.9 registry key as Jyoona suggested. Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems some of contents are missing from the windows registry key,

and this can be happening when MS Excel is downgraded.

To fix this issue, Please go to regedit and delete [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT-->TypeLib-->{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} --> 1.9]

and see if this works.

[image: Registry]

Comment: Please note that 1.9 referes Office 2016. If you see different registry key which is empty. You can erase it.

Comment: doesn't work in my case sadly

Comment: WARNING. For those thinking of trying this. It could cause major issues to delete this key. I tried this and now nothing works for my application and it is having issues with anything Excel. Please ensure this is the correct solution for you before doing this.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is risky.

I had this issue after installing Office 2003 over a 2016 install.

Repairing Office 2016 fixed it.